# What is the lifespan of a human skeletal muscle cell (such as in the biceps)?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, human-anatomy, development, human-physiology

I have read that most human skeletal muscles (such as those in the biceps) cannot multiply after development (except for exceptional situations of severe damage that involve satellite cells) and that human adults generally have the same number of muscle cells as they did in their childhood or teen years. However, I have also read that skeletal muscle cells have an average lifespan of 10-15 years. If both facts are true, wouldn't that suggest that humans would lose most of their muscle cells by 10-15 years of age? If only the first fact is true, it would seem that the lifespan of skeletal muscle cells is approximately the same as the lifespan of the individual owner.